# Trigger cross domain YQL ajax request with input onBlur

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

I have a form to collect information about a product (i.e. from Amazon). I am attempting to trigger a YQL ajax request on blur of the URL input. Currently, no errors in console, but no results either. Here is my form input:

```
<div class="uk-form-row">
            <div class="uk-form-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('item_url'); ?></div>
            <div class="uk-form-controls "><input type="text" name="jform[item_url]"   id="jform[item_url]" value="<?php if (!empty($this->item->id)) { echo $this->item->item_url;}; ?>" class="uk-form-large uk-width-medium-1-1" placeholder="http://" aria-required="required" required="required"/></div>
          </div> 
              <script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery( "#jform[item_url]" ).blur(function() {
              var path = jQuery('#jform[item_url]').val();
          requestCrossDomain(path, function(results) {
   jQuery('#url_results').html(results);
    });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="url_results">
          </div>
```

My function:

```
    // Accepts a url and a callback function to run.
function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {

    // If no url was passed, exit.
    if ( !site ) {
        alert('No site was passed.');
        return false;
    }

    // Take the provided url, and add it to a YQL query. Make sure you encode it!
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=cbFunc';

    // Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
    // Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
    jQuery.getJSON( yql, cbFunc );

    function cbFunc(data) {
    // If we have something to work with...
    if ( data.results[0] ) {
        // Strip out all script tags, for security reasons.
        // BE VERY CAREFUL. This helps, but we should do more. 
        data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');

        // If the user passed a callback, and it
        // is a function, call it, and send through the data var.
        if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(data);
        }
    }
    // Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.
    else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLY66/2/

Comment: Looks wrong `jQuery( "#jform[item_url]" )` Should be: `jQuery("#jform\\[item_url\\]" )`

Comment: I tried that in the fiddle. Still not working

Comment: beware that using getJSON, you are waiting for JSON data to be returned from server, but you ask for XML, use $.get() instead. See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/FLY66/9/  Check your console, data are returned from server. Or to get JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/FLY66/10/

Comment: Thanks - any idea why no results appear? Ideally I am looking to display just the h1 tag, and a few other elements from the result

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but using JSON you should use `data.query.results` But better would be than you check yourself what returns server, use your console

Comment: I am trying to do this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery--net-10225 , to confirm details of an amazon product (or some other product on some other site) when a user pastes a url into the input.

Comment: I guess YQL API has changed since 2010

Answer (score 0):

This issue is more related to your server. You can simply set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your server. Look for your server language to see how to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Setting it to * will accept cross-domain AJAX requests from any domain. 
Another alternative is use 'JSONP' data type for returned data.

**References**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control